# Node.js concurrent requests issue

Tags: node.js, http, concurrency, server

I have created node.js https server. When I hit the server with 100 requests at concurrency of 1 then the response is given in very short time say 0.100 sec. As I increase the concurrency lets say 100 concurrent requests, response time goes on increasing until the last request is served. It goes on increasing on subsequent requests and it reaches up to 7-8 secs to give response till the end. 
Doesn't node.js handle the concurrent requests?

```
flag var s = https.createServer(options, function onapprequest(request, response) { 
    if (request.method == 'POST') { 
        var body = ''; 
        request.on('data', function (chunk) { 
            body += chunk; }
        ); 
        request.on('end', function () { 
            try { 
                json = JSON.parse(body); 
            } 
            catch (e) { 
                log.info("parsing err"); 
            } 
            PreProcessing(); 
            function PreProcessing() { 
                // some processing... 
            } 
        }); 
    }}).listen(port); 
    servers.push(s);
```

Comment: It depends on how exactly you're testing (over localhost or over a network, server configuration, etc). Does is take 8 seconds in total to process all the (10K) requests?

Comment: I am running the server over my machine while the database is sitting on another machine. It doesn't take 8 secs to process all, instead it goes on increasing till the end of the requests. Starting from 0.250 seconds it does on increasing for the subsequent requests and finally it reaches 0.500, 0.7, 0.9, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5......8.5, 9 s etc just for 100 requests. If I hit more than hundred requests then the timing goes on increasing more than that.

Comment: You should probably post some code, since you're now talking about databases. There are various things that can cause request times to increase, from connection pools that are filling up to improper async handling to undersized hardware.

Comment: var s = https.createServer(options,
function onapprequest(request, response) {
if (request.method == 'POST') {
var body = '';
request.on('data', function (chunk) {
body += chunk;
});
request.on('end', function () {
try {
json = JSON.parse(body);
} catch (e) {
log.info("parsing err");
}
PreProcessing();
function PreProcessing() {
// some processing...
}
}
});
}
}).listen(port);
servers.push(s);
});
}

Comment: Please add your code to the question, comments aren't really appropriate.